# How to convert date to string date in php?

Tags: php, string, date, format

I am trying to convert a date '2019-04-18' to something like this '18 Apr 2019' in php.

```
$date=date_create("2019-04-18");
echo date_format($date,'jS F Y');
```

It is giving me output like this :

```
18th April 2019
```

But i need  output to be '18 Apr 2019' ie: 3 letters of month

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: did u checked the given solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `M` here for month and `d` for day:

```
$date=date_create("2019-04-18");
echo date_format($date,'d M Y'); // 18 Apr 2019
```

According to [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

`d` => Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros **(e.g 01 to 31)**

`M` => A short textual representation of a month, three letters **(e.g  Jan through Dec)**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tune date formatting like below,

```
echo date_format($date,'d M Y');
```

for more details or the link from where I created this format is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of F and jS you need to use d and M

```
echo date_format($date,'d M Y');
```

The above script will print following output

```
// 18 Apr 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$date=date_create("2019-04-18");
echo date_format($date,'jS M Y');

echo "<br>";
echo date_format($date,'j M Y');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.